# Probability calculation101

Tags: probability

Suppose a bag contains 10 balls of which 3 are red, 2 are blue and 5 are yellow. Suppose 4 balls are drawn randomly from the bag. What is the probability that 2 red balls and 2 blue balls are chosen?

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are much more likely to get useful answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A 'multinomial' probability:

${10 \choose 4}$ unordered ways to select four balls from among 10.

${3 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}{5 \choose 0}$ unordered  ways to
select 2 red, 2 blue, and 0 yellow balls.

I will leave it to you to explain why this works and to get the
numerical value of the probability.